# Пытаюсь добавить кнопку в Django админку

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Итак, я использую кастоизированную админку (grappelli)
Мне надо добавить свою кнопку с функционалом.
Использовал документацию - https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html
Вот еще - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70319606/importerror-cannot-import-name-url-from-django-conf-urls-after-upgrading-to

Воздал timetable\templates\admin\change_list.html
код в нем:

```html
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %} {% load i18n %} 

{% block object-tools-items %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <li>
        {% comment %} <a class="historylink" href="test_data/">My custom admin page</a> {% endcomment %}
        <a href="#" class="grp-add-link grp-state-focus">Add ТЕСТ (ТаМ ДЕ НАДА)</a>
        прив))
    </li>
{% endblock %}
```

Если смотреть в обычную админку (без grappelli), то кнопка появилась
Если С ней, то кнопки нет.

Если редачить
venv\Lib\site-packages\grappelli\templates\admin\change_list.html
, то кнопка появляется, но это не дело...

Как сделать так, чтоб grappelli наконец увидел мою кнопку?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вы неправильно экстендите.

Если вы обратите внимание на [исходники django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html) и [исходник django-grappelli](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli/blob/master/grappelli/templates/admin/change_list.html), там используется `{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}`.

Comment: Я тоже думал что тут что-то не так с экстендом. Но если я сделаю так:
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
В файле timetable\templates\admin\change_list.html,
то ни к чему хорошему эту не привело. С grappelli - без изменений, а если с чистой django, то вся админка ломается (исчезает отображение)